# sending state from child to parent class in react js

Tags: reactjs

im trying to change state of article2 state which is in the parent class call ed welcom.js
the onclick funtion is in quiz.js which is the child class. so on click of that function i want to change state of the state in parent class any help?

parent class state

i want to change this to true on some condition in the function in the child class

```
article1: false,
article2: false,
article3: false,
article4: false,
article5: true
```

child class function

```
 loadNextChallenege = () => {
    if (this.props.rankValue === 1) {
      this.setState({
        //article state
      });
    } else if (this.props.rankValue === 2) {
      this.setState({
        //article state
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass down a function from the parent via props, then call that in the child (and pass in any necessary parameters)

Example Parent

```
function updateState(value){
     this.setState({
        //article state
      });
}
<Child updateState={this.updateState} />
```

then in the child

```
loadNextChallenege = () => {
   this.props.updateState("a value");
}
```

Comment: why vote down like whats wrong with you its a question im asking??

Comment: the button that call the functoin next challeneg is in the child class how will that trigger the parent class??no refrence of that shown above

Answer (score 0):

> Parent Component

```
    import Child from './Child';

    class Parent extends React.Component {
       state={
            something:''
          }


     getFromChild(data){
        this.setState({something:data })
     }

        render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Child 
                        sendToParent={this.getFromChild} // catch child state
                        />
                    </div>
                )
        }
    }
```

> Child Component

```
    class Child extends React.Component {
    state={
       userInput:''
    }


    handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value, //update state as user enters input

            })
    }

    handleClick(e){
    this.props.sendToParent(this.state.userInput) //pass child state up to parent
    }
        render() {
                return (
                <div>
                    <input
                        name='entry'
                        value={this.state.userInput}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClick}><span>Send State To 
                     Parent</span></Button>

                </div>
                )
        }
    }
```

Every time user enters something it'll get saved in the state in child component and when button clicked, the state will be sent up to parent component and you can catch it from your parent component as above. Let me know if you didn't understand anything or have any questions.